What is /usr/local/bin/crpdspt?
I have a binary called crpdspt located at /usr/local/bin/. Google search provides really little results. It has a plist at /Library/LaunchDaemons/.
Any idea what that is?

Stuff in /usr/local/bin is user-installed. Can you run ls -l /usr/local/bin/crpdspt and add the result to the question? And the content of the plist as well?

Please update your question with the output of the following command: codesign -dvv /usr/local/bin/crpdspt
